# How to recompile static gfortran and gcc libraries with fPIC

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, gfortran, fpic

I am compiling a shared library (for linux systems) from a Fortran source which I would like to distribute to researchers around the world.  I can successfully build with `gfortran -shared -o mylib.so ...`.  Unfortunately, `ldd mylib.so` reveals dependencies on various gfortran and gcc libraries, and I find this totally unacceptable:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff995bd000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fa5227fa000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa5224f1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa5222da000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa521f10000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007fa521cd1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000561be2268000)
```

I want my programs to execute out-of-the-box without requiring the user to know how to install gfortran on their machine and how to make sure they have the required libraries (*e.g.* `libgfortran.so.3` and not `libgfortran.so.4`).

Therefore, I *insist* on statically linking all the gfotran libraries into my shared object.  Unfortunately `gfortran -shared -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc` fails with the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a(error.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgfortran.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Obviously, the `.a` files distributed with gfortran and gcc have not been compiled with position independent code. **Question:** I need step-by-step instructions on rebuilding the static versions of gfortran library files listed above with position independent code, so that I may successfully build my own shared library, with the gfortran libraries statically incorporated into them, achieving reduced dependences.

Comment: Why not just compile your library statically? Note you can distribute the gcc libraries with your code too.

Comment: I would find linking all gcc libraries "totally unacceptable" for research libraries I use unless it is very  large closed-source software (standalone). Note that there are many subtle issues with static libc and you must think **very carefully** about compatibility with users GCC.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for your input.  I must obtain a *shared* library in the end, since it is being called from within *Mathematica* using a mechanism which I have no control over.

Comment: @VladimirF How would I distribute the dependent gcc libraries with my program, and tell my users to place them in the correct directory on their machine so that the executable can be successfully run?

Comment: The same way you distribute your library. The fact that the final use case is in Mathematica and not Fortran makes it somewhat more likely you will be safer from clashes of various libgfortran versions. Still be careful about libgcc and others. Mathematica may ship their own versions or it may use the version from the user's distro, I am not sure.

Comment: @VladimirF It's not working.  I tried just copying all of the gfortran libraries, `libgfortran.s0.3`, `libm.s0.6`, ... *etc.* into the same directory as where `mylib.so` is.  But I still got "image not found" problems.  But I think I'm on the right track.  Now I need to make `mylib.so` point to the same directory so it finds all the dependent libraries.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: libgfortran.a is built without `-fPIC` so you'll not be able to link it into a shared library. You could rebuild GCC with appropriate `CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET` to fix that.